# Making OpenStack Grizzly work on Ubuntu Raring (13.04)

Tags: server, 13.04, cloud, openstack

Canonical says that they have "tightly integrated" OpenStack Grizzly into their Raring Ringtail release. Yet I fail to make this work at all, currently.

So I got a fresh install of Raring Server on a physical box.

My first attempt was to follow the official documentation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/ubuntucloud.html

Unfortunately, these instructions are simply outdated, despite the /13.04/ in the URL. They are just cut and paste from an earlier version. I failed in the middle of the "Install OpenStack Compute (Nova)" section because the nova-manage user subcommand just isn't there any more in the Grizzly release; they have moved to keystone.

Not that nobody would have noticed yet:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1106139

As a next attempt, I want to DevStack.org. No luck on 13.04; just not working. I re-installed the host server to 12.04 and used the DevStack.org grizzly branch and was able to get something up and running, yet there are many issues with a DevStack setup system. (Different story.)

So I wonder if nobody ever tried to create a single-node OpenStack server on top of Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) with the Grizzy release of OpenStack; except going down the MAAS / Juju path with 10+ machines.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: I've been trying this (first with raring, now with saucy). I'm using KVM+Libvirt on one (powerful, 16G Ram machine). I then have MaaS manage the KVM machines and then use Juju on top to deploy openstack. The main place I have been stuck is with charms failing to deploy, but it appears that might be my fault: http://askubuntu.com/questions/365216/whats-the-lastest-version-of-openstack-that-i-can-deploy-with-juju-where-can-f

Comment: I hope this link with help you http://www.hastexo.com/resources/docs/installing-openstack-essex-20121-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin