# What's the lastest version of Openstack that I can deploy with Juju? Where can find this information?

Tags: server, juju, cloud, openstack

I've been trying to deploy openstack.

I thought Havana was the latest, but deployed nova cloud controller, and the log said `2013-10-24 19:13:25 INFO juju juju-log.go:66 nova-cloud-controller/0: FATAL ERROR: Invalid Cloud Archive release specified: precise-updates/havana`.

Is there somewhere to see what the latest Juju deployable (with the standard repositories) version is?

Or am I just using the wrong format when I specify `openstack-origin: cloud:precise-updates/havana` in the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You openstack-origin configuration is not quite correct - try:

```
openstack-origin: cloud:precise-havana
```

other valid options include:

```
cloud:precise-havana/updates
cloud:precise-havana/proposed (for testing)
```

You can find out about the latest OpenStack releases for Ubuntu 12.04 on the [Ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive)